# Advice? External USB harddrive accidentally unplugged (no activity at time). Re-plugged, but `mountpoint`/`findmnt`/`lsblk` disagree if mounted?

Tags: usb-drive, external-hdd, fsck, btrfs, mountpoint

[(*This really isn't an unbuntu-specific question, but yeah...*)]

So I just accidentally bumped and and unplugged the cable on an external USB harddrive.

- There was no activity at the time.
- It's btrfs (one big partition the whole drive, about 2TB... (I *think* it's spinning rust, not an SSD -- I dunno, it's just something I had in my box of random old things I inherited from I dunno where))

---

I just plugged it back in, and...

- `mountpoint [[path]]` #=> "`[[path]] is a mountpoint`"
- `lsblk` doesn't show it as having a mountpoint
- `findmnt` #=>

```
TARGET      SOURCE                              FSTYPE  OPTIONS                                                                                     
/           /dev/sda3[/@/.snapshots/1/snapshot] btrfs   rw,relatime,ssd,discard=async,space_cache=v2,subvolid=266,subvol=/@/.snapshots/1/snapshot   
[...]                                                                                                                                               
[...]                                                                                                                                               
[...]                                                                                                                                               
└─[[path]]  /dev/sdb1                           btrfs   ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/
```

- but
   `sudo ls [[path]]`
  #=>
  `ls: reading directory '[[path]]': Input/output error`

---

What should I do/check?

Like, I am *aware* of `fsck`,
but I don't know anything specific about how/why to use it, or what related/alternative tools I should use...?

Basically, what are my unknown-unknowns here?
How are you generally supposed to deal with this kind of situation?

Comment: Can't you just reboot and mount it again? Unless you want specifically to mount it back under this session to save something unsaved (like those dark times when I had used VM from external USB HDD for my job) it's not worth it to bother with all those glitches. After that just do normal filesystem check and repair.

Comment: Sorry, should've said more explicitly like: I assume I can just `umount` it, or at the worst reboot, but I figured I should first check in case someone goes "no! don't reboot yet! first you should [do X] because [arcane cache/journaling details]!" Anyway, [`umount`, un-and-re- plug, remount] seems to have worked perfectly. So I guess should make that the accepted answer to this question...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:
I should've made it more explicit that I was *pretty* sure that I could just do
`umount [mountpoint]`
or at the worst reboot,
but I figured I should first check in case someone went like:

> no! don't reboot yet!
> first you should [do X]
> because [arcane cache/journaling details that are probably beyond you]!

However, no one I asked seemed to know of any potential hidden landmines like that,
so I just did:

- `umount [mountpoint]`
- unplugged and replugged drive
- remounted

and it seemed to work fine.